# Error message "Token is expired or invalid" is displayed when I call the API for verifying the purchase token. What can I do?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I integrated HUAWEI IAP into my app and called the relevant API to verify the payment order by referring to the official documentation, but the following error message was displayed:

{"responseCode":"6","responseMessage":"Token is expired or invalid"}

Please help.

Comment: I strongly suggest you fix your code.